# WPF XAML String.Format multiply by 100 without displaying the '%' char

Tags: wpf, xaml, string-formatting

I would like to use StringFormat to display a value between 0 and 1 like a purcentage, but without the '%' char.

i.e : `0.57`would be displayed as `57`

How to do it with StringFormat ? Is it even possible ?

Comment: Use `IValueConverter` to multiply the binded value by 100 OR instead have calculated property in class which will return `value * 100`.

Answer (score -1):

In your xaml use this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Amount, StringFormat=\{0:F0\}}"/>
```

this should display text as 22 given:

```
public sealed class ViewModel
{
    public double Amount {get; set;} /*implementing INotify*/
}
```

xaml:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:ViewModel Amount="0.22"/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

Comment: I already tried something like this but it displays 0.22. Is there a StringFormat like `"{0:P0}"` but without `%` ?

Comment: how about `StringFormat={}{0:#,#.0}`?

Comment: fair enough, your solution is then `IValueConverter` like @Rohit Vats suggested. I only tried to help sorry.